# Problems with testing Angular code using Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

I would like to test my Angular code. I use Node.js 0.10.28, Grunt, Karma as a test framework and PhantomJS as a browser.

I get this error:

```
PALM00545424A:Hello-World user$ grunt karma:unit

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket KPTCteUUYsm4XkgYuvGT with id 70458581
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'module.factory')
  at /Users/user/repos/Hello-World/src/client/api.js:33


Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

This is my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

  // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
  basePath: './',


  // frameworks to use
  // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],


  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: [

    // Angular
    'src/bower/angular/angular.js',
    'src/bower/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'src/bower/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
    'src/bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

    // Client source code
    'src/client/**/*.js',

    // Tests
    'src/tests/client/**/*.js'
  ],
  ...
```

Any idea?

Edit: This is the test code. The test runs successfully if the Angular dependencies are not included.

src/tests/client/test.js

```
describe('some tests', function() {
    it('should run', function () {
    var val = "Hello World";
    expect(val).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

This is the client code that fails:

```
module.factory("$RPC", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        call: function(m, f, d, c) {
            var res = {value: null, error: null, loaded: false, loading: true};
            $http.post("/api/"+m+"/"+f, d)
                .success(function(value) {
                    res.value = value;
                    res.loaded = true;
                    res.loading = false;
                    console.log("[success]", m, f, d, res);
                    if(typeof c === 'function') {
                        c(null, res);
                    }
                })
                .error(function(value) {
                    res.error = value;
                    res.loaded = true;
                    res.loading = false;
                    console.log("[error]", m, f, d, res);
                    if(typeof c === 'function') {
                        c(res.error, res);
                    }
                });
            return res;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Let's see your test as well as the code it's testing

Comment: Test is included. Right now I'm not testing any client code. I just want to set up the Angular testing first.

Comment: Where the error occurs is shown in your question.  The reason why?  No idea, I'd have to see the code.  The karma.conf.js, as much of it as you posted, looks fine

Comment: I have added the full error context, I was not able to post everything due to the Stackoverflow restrictions. I get the error when running the test

Comment: Without seeing the code that is failing the test, I can't help you.

Comment: I've added the failing client code. It is not tested, just linked with karma to be imported.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved.

`'src/client/**/*.js'` is not a good solution, because the imports are in alphabetical order then. Make sure that your main module is imported first.

Just list every dependency and only use wildcards `**/*` where order is no matter.

Comment: Using the wild cards is fine.  My suggestion would be to use Yeoman and let it set everything up for you.

Comment: Why downvoting when don't even know the context? Using wildcards is not always fine. E.g. if the file ```app.js``` is defining the module and ```api.js``` uses it, ```api.js``` must come after ```app.js```. So you mustn't do an alphabetical import, you have to define the correct order in this context and use wildcards for the rest of your source files.

Comment: Create a Yeoman generated scaffold and take a look at the generated karma.conf.js file